# Unexpected output while printing system time using C

Tags: c, pointers, time, time.h

I have been writing a code which prints the current system date and time using the `time.h` header file and getting an unexpected output. NOTE: This excerpt is a part of a bigger system.I have simplified the code to point out the erroneous portion.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
typedef struct dater
{
    int date;
    int month;
    int year;
}DATER;

typedef struct timer
{
    int hour;
    int min;
    int sec;
}TIMER;

DATER * current_date()
{
    DATER * d;
    time_t currentTime;
    time(&currentTime);
    struct tm *myTime=localtime(&currentTime);
    d->date=myTime->tm_mday;
    d->month=myTime->tm_mon+1;
    d->year=myTime->tm_year+1900;
    return d;
}

TIMER * current_time()
{
    TIMER * t;
    time_t currentTime;
    time(&currentTime);
    struct tm *myTime=localtime(&currentTime);
    t->hour=myTime->tm_hour;
    t->min=myTime->tm_min;
    t->sec=myTime->tm_sec;
    return t;
}
int main()
{
    DATER * d=current_date();
    TIMER * t=current_time();

    printf("Today's Date Is: %02d.%02d.%d\n",d->date,d->month,d->year);
    printf("TIme Is: %02d:%02d:%02d",t->hour,t->min,t->sec);

    return 1;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Today's Date Is: 17.39.17
Time Is: 39:17:17
```

The issue seems to get resolved if I put the statement `printf("Today's Date Is: %02d.%02d.%d\n",d->date,d->month,d->year);` before the `current_time()` function call.

I am not really understanding why this is happening as I am storing the date and time in two different structures at two different instances.

PS- I know this is an elaborate method.But as I had mentioned earlier, I am using this in a bigger project

Comment: You say that the output is unexpected. What output did you expect?

Comment: your pointers don't point somewhere valid

Comment: You write to `DATER * d;` without the pointer being initialized. You also must take care to not return the address of the local variable -- let it be an argument and let the user supply the memory.

Comment: Don't you get some warnings about using `d` or `t` without being initialized?

Comment: You could return a copy of the struct instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really turn on warnings.

```
$ gcc k.c -Wall -Wextra
k.c: In function ‘current_date’:
k.c:23:12: warning: ‘d’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   23 |     d->date=myTime->tm_mday;
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
k.c: In function ‘current_time’:
k.c:35:12: warning: ‘t’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   35 |     t->hour=myTime->tm_hour;
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You have not allocated any memory. `d` is just an uninitialized pointer. Either change the function to return a struct or allocate memory first.

```
DATER * current_date()
{
    DATER *d = malloc(sizeof *d);
```

or

```
DATER current_date()
{
    DATER d;
    time_t currentTime;
    time(&currentTime);
    struct tm *myTime=localtime(&currentTime);
    d.date=myTime->tm_mday;
    d.month=myTime->tm_mon+1;
    d.year=myTime->tm_year+1900;
    return d;
}
```

I'm actually a bit surprised your code does not crash. That's a more likely scenario.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out a minute later after posting it here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could also propose `-Werror`, where the code haven´t even been compiled.